# C# RichTextBox выделить слово цветом.

Tags: c#

Есть RichTextBox.
при каком - то определённом событии в RTB записывается новая строка.

```
rtb.Text+=DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()+"\r\n"+SOmeText;
```

Каким образом ДАТУ выделить в другой цвет?

Если можно, с небольшим примером. :)

Comment: Вы хотите изменять цвет по кнопке (вручную) или автоматически?

Comment: да нет, зачем по кнопке. Автоматически. То есть, новая строка добавилась и определённое слово в ней какого - то цвета. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот так, например:

```
string str = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
richTextBox1.AppendText(str + "\r\n" + "SOmeText" + "\r\n");
int i = 0;
while (i <= richTextBox1.Text.Length - str.Length)
{
    i = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(str, i);
    if (i < 0) break;
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = i;
    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = str.Length;
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
    i += str.Length;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает. :)

Comment: всегда пожалуйста :)